# Safari extension: how to get current url from injected script?

Tags: safari-extension

I am trying to get the current url from injected script but it seems impossible because of the permission.
From the official document, I got:

> Injected scripts cannot access the SafariApplication or SafariExtension classes.

Is there any solution or w/a? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use `window.location.href` to get the URL of the page the script is injected into.

Scripts are injected into each iframe as well as the main page, so you might want to use a check like `if (window == window.top)` to if you are only interested in the main page.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Finally, I sent a message to the global.html to get the url. It seems using message to communicate between global.html and injected script is a common pattern for some tasks, such as cross-domain ajax.

Comment: very helpful. For me, it helped me in issuing a command to injected script after receiving that command in global script :)